# Mysql query returns wrong rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a simple mysql database where user has its own events table and invited events table.

```
User-->>Own events (user_id is foreign key )
User and Own events-->>Invited Events(user_id is foreign key, event id is foreign key)
```

I want to get `OWN EVENT` details from `Invited Events` where `user_id` is equal to some number

Example:

[image]

I try:

```
$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT A1.event_id,A1.root_folder,A1.event_name,A1.date,A1.location,A2.user_id FROM OWN_EVENTS A1, INVITED_EVENTS A2 WHERE A2.user_id=$user_id");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
    $rows[]=$r;
}
```

This supposed give me (one row) event details of `event_id=3`  where `user_id=58`   but this returns all the rows in the `OWN_EVENTS` table.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you query returns cartesian product.

You need to tell the optimizer how the two tables are connected with each other.

```
SELECT  A1.event_id,A1.root_folder,A1.event_name,A1.date,A1.location,A2.user_id 
FROM    OWN_EVENTS A1 
        INNER JOIN INVITED_EVENTS A2 
           ON A1.columnName = A2.columnsName  // columns that defines their relationship
WHERE   A2.user_id=$user_id
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: thanks for quick answer that works fine, I guess I need to learn more about joins in sql.